# how to fix dynamically multiple attachment of file issue

Tags: javascript

I am trying to attach file on button click and there is one "add" button for more attachment with dynamic id generated for separate input field. But whenever the index is above 9 it gives an error of undefined index.

```
var index = $("div.dropDownAttachSection-"+classId+"-"+splAttrId).children().last().index();
index = index-1;

var tabContentView = '';

tabContentView +='<form id="wk_form_AttrOptionAttachment'+index+'" name="wk_form_AttrOptionAttachment'+index+'">';
tabContentView +='<div class="col-md-12 PaddingLZeroWO dropDownAttachDiv">';
tabContentView +='<div class="col-md-10">';
tabContentView +='<div class="">';
tabContentView +='<input type="file" id="wk_dropDownAttachment-'+splAttrId+'-'+index+'" name="wk_dropDownAttachment-'+splAttrId+'-'+index+'" onchange="uploadAttrOptionAttachments(this,'+classId+','+splAttrId+');" class="filestyle" data-dragdrop="false" '+mandatFlag+'" data-buttonBefore="true" data-placeholder="No files attached" multiple readonly />';
//tabContentView +='<input type="hidden" id="wk_dropDownAttachment'+index+'-hidden" name="wk_dropDownAttachment'+index+'-hidden" class="input-xs" readonly />';
tabContentView +='</div>';
tabContentView +='</div>';
tabContentView +='<div class="col-md-2">';
tabContentView +='<div class="">';
tabContentView +='<button type="button" onClick="RemoveAttachment(this);" class="btn btn-xs btn-default"><i class="fa fa-times"></i></button>';
tabContentView +='</div>';
tabContentView +='</div>';
tabContentView +='</div>';
tabContentView +='</div>';
tabContentView +='</form>';
tabContentView +='<input type="hidden" id="wk_dropDownAttachment-'+splAttrId+'-'+index+'-hidden" name="wk_dropDownAttachment-'+splAttrId+'-'+index+'-hidden" class="input-xs" readonly />';
$("div.dropDownAttachSection-"+classId+"-"+splAttrId).after().append(tabContentView);
```

I expect more than files should be uploaded to the server.

Comment: We can't help without the line which cause the error, from this, it doesn't look like it's here. Also it can be a good idea if you put a short working example here. What I can tell is, when you get the index here, and you have 8 items, you will get 7, because the counting starts from 0. You deduct one, and you create a new input field. So there's at least one field which has the same 'id' like the other one.

Comment: Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: if ($errorFlag == 1) {
            if(file_exists($target_file)){
                echo true;
            }else if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES["$file"]["tmp_name"], $target_file)) {

                echo $fullFineName;
            } else {
                echo "Sorry, there was an error uploading your file";
            }
        }